# Android looping through KvmSerializable

Tags: java, android

I have a Serializable object

```
KvmSerializable serializable = (KvmSerializable)object;
```

Currently I am hardcoding to set my property

```
this.setProperty(0, serializable.getProperty(0));
this.setProperty(1, serializable.getProperty(1));
```

I want to know if it is possible to loop through serializable->Properties->ElementData and get the index of the property I need by hardcoding the name instead?